# Muting Blocking or Filtering

Tags: feature-request

The truth on this site has less buoyancy than passionate ignorance.

We need to be able to filter people. Without this feature, contributing puts you in a huge risk. Arguing back with intellectual dishonesty will not help anyone.

This website relies on labored and paid for information which it gets to collect for free, and thus far will only maintain a place for that information to die defamed, because as I see from all the past questions about this, it has refused to acknowledge the needs of the laborers it benefits from.

Answer (score 9):

There is no reason to block a specific individual.

You can:

- ignore their posts/messages/comments if not productive
- flag them for a moderator if they are rude and need to be removed

Blocking someone won't help either side.

Comment: The reason is because this website no longer gets information from knowledgeable people who are used to this as a feature in every other comparable resource.